# Resource not found exception

Tags: android, datepicker

I am trying to use datepicker in my project. But as soon as I run the project, it throws "Resource not found exception" and following line appears when I drag datepicker in xml file

```
The following classes could not be found:
- CalendarView (Change to android.widget.CalendarView, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
- DatePicker (Change to android.widget.DatePicker, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
```

logcat entries are as follows:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: 

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dateandtimepick/com.example.dateandtimepick.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x16
```

How can I rectify the code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like a bad import statement to me...

Comment: @Goddchen then what should I do?

Comment: which api are you using?

Comment: The following classes could not be found: is that an run time exception if so post the full stack trace, otherwise post your xml file and the API version what you are using

Comment: @AlexChengalan  api level 17

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x16

You are trying to set `int` value in

`tetview.setText()` or `Toast.makeText()`, which it will take as string resource id.

So try to give int value in like this

`.setText(""+intvalue)` or `Toast.makeText(context,""+intvalue,..)`

Comment: I was dealing with a similar problem. Actually, it was my lack of attention. My code was `setText( 'A' + i )`. It took a long time to realize that `'A' + i` was, actually, a reference to an Resource (because a `char` may be interpreted as an `int`). So, if you get stuck on something like this, remember to check it. To fix, just change it to `setText( String.valueOf('A' + i) )`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the "Resource not found" exception by re-installing the Android SDK. For some reason, while packing the apk, the SDK tools weren't packing the resources. Its' a build error (silent error) that yells only at runtime. I did not need to reinsatll JDK or eclipse.

Answer (score -1):

1. Try to clean to Project to rebuild the R.java
2. Rebuild the xml by creating a new xml,I guess maybe you forget to add the namespace (xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android")

   Hope I can help.